# How to avoid explicit invocation in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

I  created a chatbot in Dialogflow, and then integrated with Google Assistant. It will invoke my app only by saying"talk to", but I want to make chatbot initate the conversation without the query.

Comment: Can you show here, what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can't initiate the conversation under Actions on Google. The conversation model explicitly requires the user to take the first action.

You don't give the context under what conditions you want to start the conversation, but you can look into features such as [daily updates](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily) or [notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) to see if they meet your needs.